# TYPO3 & MAX_JOIN_SIZE error via Shared Server - Possible Workaround?

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have multiple JOINS which by itself work fine. Now I combined them and get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

I'm on a hosted shared server ... is there any way to SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in TYPO3? E.g. in the LocalConfiguration.php

```
<?php
return array(
...
'DB' => array(
    'database' => 'database',
    'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
    'host' => 'password',
    'password' => 'password',
    'port' => port,
    'username' => 'port',
    'init_commands' => array(
        'big_selects' => 'SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1',
    ),
),
...
);
?>
```

Comment: Asuming you use your big Select in your Repository. Run `$query->statement('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'); $query->execute();` bevor you run your Big Query could help. (I know its not an answer to the question if its possible to set it globaly). No access to the mysql.ini/cnf ? Have you asked the hoster? Most times they are willing to help.